Dataframe from dictionary list in Julia
I'm dealing with a multi-level dictionary in Julia. The outermost dictionary is Dict{String, Any}, which looks like this:
`Dict{String, Any} with 38 entries:
  "2024-11-15:169" => Dict{String, Any}("395.0"=>Any[Dict{String, Any}("mini"=>…
  "2024-06-28:29"  => Dict{String, Any}("418.0"=>Any[Dict{String, Any}("mini"=>…
  "2025-06-20:386" => Dict{String, Any}("750.0"=>Any[Dict{String, Any}("mini"=>…`


Each value is also a dictionary Dict{String, Any} with:
`Dict{String, Any} with 112 entries:
  "475.0" => Any[Dict{String, Any}("mini"=>false, "settlementType"=>"P", "low52…
  "500.0" => Any[Dict{String, Any}("mini"=>false, "settlementType"=>"P", "low52…
  "456.0" => Any[Dict{String, Any}("mini"=>false, "settlementType"=>"P", "low52…`

Ultimately, I want to create a dictionary that has values which are dataframes. I.e. assign to each key from the outermost dictionary a dataframe based on the inner dictionary (With columns like "strike"=[475, 500, 456] or "mini"=[false, false, false] for example).
What does the Any[...] mean in the inner dictionary? How can I get rid of it because I only have dictionary types inside? Then, how do I efficiently collect the info from each dictionary into dataframe columns?
Thanks.
I tried just parsing it with DataFrame(outerdict) but it creates some kind of weird multi-level column index, again with the Any's. Also, with dictionaries as dataframe values it feels quite inefficient to manually create new columns every time from the dictionary entries.

It is not clear from your question what you need.
So let's assume we have a nested dictionary:
julia> d = Dict(:df1=>[Dict(:a=>10,:b=>20),Dict(:a=>11,:b=>21)], :df2=>[Dict(:a=>10,:b=>20),Dict(:a=>11,:b=>21)])
Dict{Symbol, Vector{Dict{Symbol, Int64}}} with 2 entries:
  :df2 => [Dict(:a=>10, :b=>20), Dict(:a=>11, :b=>21)]
  :df1 => [Dict(:a=>10, :b=>20), Dict(:a=>11, :b=>21)]

We can convert it to a dictionary of data frames:
julia> dfs = Dict(keys(d) .=> DataFrame.(values(d)))
Dict{Symbol, DataFrame} with 2 entries:
  :df2 => 2×2 DataFrame…
  :df1 => 2×2 DataFrame…

Were a single data frame looks like this:
julia> dfs[:df1]
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b
     │ Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────
   1 │    10     20
   2 │    11     21

The trick is the correct usage of broadcasting.
The Any[] in the inner dictionary means a Vector of elements of type Any. Any is an abstract type - a supertype for any Julia type. In my example having d = Dict(:df1=>Any[Dict(:a=>10,:b=>20),Dict(:a=>11,:b=>21)], :df2=>Any[Dict(:a=>10,:b=>20),Dict(:a=>11,:b=>21)]) would not have changed anything (except for performance which would be lower as the usage of abstract containers is not recommended in Julia).
